# Wordpress $wpdb->options

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Where does `$wpdb->options` come from?

I can't see `$wpdb-options()` function or `$this->options` so how is this achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$wpdb->options` is a property of the object `$wpdb` (which is an instance of the class `wpdb`).

It's value is the name of the options table in the database, usually `wp_options`.

Comment: So where is $wpdb->options defined?

Comment: Do you know where it is defined?

Comment: It's set in the class `wpdb` inside the `wp-includes/wp-db.php`.

Comment: Theres actually a loop inwhich its set:
   foreach ( (array) $this->tables as $table )
   $this->$table = $this->prefix . $table;

Answer (score 5):

Okay, here is a *complete* clarification of the confusion I can see here.

`$wpdb` is an object for querying the database. The `$wpdb->options` property is merely the **name** of the options table in the database. It does *not* store nor contain the contents of that table.

WordPress options (or settings) are stored, updated and read using the functions `add_option()`, `update_option()` and `get_option()` respectively.

You can also get **all** options using `get_alloptions()`.

The reason you should use $wpdb properties to reference tables in your SQL queries is that the table prefix is *user defined*, and you cannot assume it will always be called 'wp_tablename'.

Answer (score 1):

`$wpdb->options` is defined through `wp_set_wpdb_vars()` in `wp-includes/load.php`.

This line sets the table names via a call to the set_prefix function:

```
$prefix = $wpdb->set_prefix( $table_prefix );
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

"wpdb" is class to interact with database. Its in "wp-db.php". since i don't know what exactly you are asking about this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class) might be helpful for you.

Comment: Yeh but I don't understand where the $wpdb->options come from (the options bit)

Answer (score 0):

I think people are struggling to understand your question. Maybe provide a bit more detail or context.

If you are asking where the options originally came from, then the answer is that they are set during setup and in the WP Admin pages. They are then stored in the wp_options table in your database, and retrieved into the $wpdb->options variable that is a member of the $wpdb object when Wordpress loads.

Comment: Yeh but where is $wpdb-options in the files? Where is it defined, not what it does but where is it?

Comment: Oh, you probably won't find a single spot where all the options are defined. Each option has a key (string) and a value. Different places in the code will query the DB for the value associated with a particular key. There is a function "get_option" in "functions.php" for doing this. It queries the table name specified by $wpdb->options. Note that plugins also use the wp_options table to store stuff.

Comment: How could I achieve the same thing?

Comment: I see get_option, I just wondered where $wpdb->options came from